# Series solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y' - e^{x^2}y = 0 $$

I've learned how to get the series solution for such differential equations when the multiplicating function is polynomial, but I have no clue what to do with another function.  Here's what I've tried :

$$ \sum_1^\infty na_nx^{n-1} - e^{x^2}\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n = 0$$

$$ \sum_0^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n - e^{x^2}\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n = 0$$

Then I'm stuck because I don't know what to do with the exponential function.  If it was polynomial, I could simply distribute it in the sum and do a variable change, but how can I treat a such case?

Thank you.

Actually, I only need to find the first few terms, not the general solution to it (which is probably complicated).

Comment: Expand $e^{x^2}$ out using its power series (about zero). Then you can multiply out the first few terms of that series with the first few terms of the series its multiplying, and do the "usual" things from there to obtain the recurrence relation for the $a_n$...

Comment: Not sure how I can do this, as the expansion of e^(x^2) has an infinity of terms.

Comment: See Cauchy products for multiplying series. In general, you'll be able to differentiate the series to get equations for your coefficients. For example, differentiating once and plugging in $x=0$ gives you an equation for $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot about Cauchy's product, which was the main reason I didn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll do a power series expansion about $x=0$.

Let $\displaystyle y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ so that $\displaystyle y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1}$.

Note that $\displaystyle e^{x^2} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(x^2)^n\over n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{2n}\over n!}$.

Substituting these back into the given ODE, we have
\begin{align}
y'-e^{x^2}y&=0\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nnx^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{2n}\over n!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n&=0.
\end{align}

Expand the first few terms of each to obtain
\begin{align}
(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2&+4a_4x^3+5a_5x^4+\cdots)\\
&-(1+x^2+{x^4\over 2!}+\cdots)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots)=0.
\end{align}
Then expand the product of the two series in the latter term,
\begin{align}
(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2&+4a_4x^3+5a_5x^4+\cdots)\\
&-\left[(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots) + (a_0x^2+a_1x^3+a_2x^4+\cdots)\right.\\
&+\left.({a_0\over 2!}x^4+{a_1\over 2!}x^5+{a_2\over 2!}x^6+\cdots)\right]=0,
\end{align}
and collect like terms:
\begin{align}
(a_1-a_0)+(2a_2-a_1)x&+(3a_3-a_2-a_0)x^2\\
&+(4a_4-a_3-a_1)x^3+(5a_5-a_4-a_2+{a_0\over 2!})x^4+\cdots=0.
\end{align}
Since the series on the left equals the series on the right, the corresponding coefficients in the series on the left must all be zero, which yields a recursive relation for $a_n$, $n\ge 1$:
\begin{align}
a_1-a_0=0 &\implies \color{blue}{a_1=a_0}\\
2a_2-a_1=0 &\implies \color{blue}{a_2=}{1\over 2}a_1=\color{blue}{{1\over 2}a_0}\\
3a_3-a_2-a_0=0 &\implies \color{blue}{a_3=}{a_2+a_0\over 2}=\color{blue}{{1\over 2}a_0}\\
4a_4-a_3-a_1=0 &\implies \color{blue}{a_4=}{a_3+a_1\over 4}=\color{blue}{{3\over 8}a_0}\\
5a_5-a_4-a_2+{a_0\over 2!}=0 &\implies \color{blue}{a_5=}{a_4+a_2-{a_0\over 2!}\over 5}=\color{blue}{{3\over 40}a_0}\\
&\quad\ \vdots
\end{align}
Note that we can find the value of $a_n$ (in terms of the parameter $a_0$) for any $n$ we desire from this recursive process.

Hence, the series solution we seek is given by
$$
\boxed{
y(x)=a_0\left(1+x+{1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 2}x^3+{3\over 8}x^4+{3\over 40}x^5+\cdots\right).}
$$

Comment: Makes sense, very clear answer.  Thanks a lot.